# Referencing a dynamic number of fields in a template in django

Tags: django, templates, forms, dynamic

It is all very simple. I have this form:

```
class add_basketForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, selected_subunits, *args, **kwargs):


    self.selected_subunits = selected_subunits
    super(add_basketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for subunit in self.selected_subunits:
        self.fields['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])] = forms.IntegerField()
```

The number of subunits are unknown. I would like to use something like this (you get the idea):

```
{% for unit in selected_subunits %}
  {{ form.su%s }} % (unit.unit__id)
{% endfor %}
```

But of course that doesn't work. My question is how do I reference those formfields in Django template language?

Answer (score 9):

In order to access the BoundField instances for your dynamic field instances, which is what gives you access to [all of the attributes and methods necessary to render the field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), you need to access the field objects using the form of `form.fieldname` rather than `form.fields[fieldname]`

Here's a potential refactoring of your form class:

```
class add_basketForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, selected_subunits, *args, **kwargs):
        super(add_basketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for subunit in self.selected_subunits:
            self.fields['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])] = forms.IntegerField()

    def su_fields(self):
        for name in self.fields:
            if name.startswith('su'):
                yield(self[name])
```

Then in your template, you should be able to iterate over the fields as you would normally expect by accessing `form.su_fields`:

```
{% for su_field in form.su_fields %}
....
{% endfor %}
```

(I had been struggling with this same problem for several hours. Thanks to [this answer from Carl Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670711/django-form-fields-not-iterating-through-instance-fields/671305#671305) and [this article on dynamic form generation from Jacob Kaplan-Moss](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) for pointing me in the right directions.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have been struggling on a personal hobby project for a month because I could not get my form working just right. I was feeling really down because I felt this was something that should just work but couldn't quite get the incantation correct. You have helped me immensely.

Answer (score 4):

Group those fields in an additional list and then simply iterate over this list.

In `__init__`:

```
self.subunit_list = []
for subunit in self.selected_subunits:
        field = forms.IntegerField()
        self.fields['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])] = field
        self.subunit_list.append(field)
```

In template:

```
{% for field in form.subunit_list %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1: best solution is not to put this in template, as it's not template logic.

Comment: What do I write inside the for loop to show the input field? It seems to me that I still have the problem of referencing each "unknown" fieldname in the loop, e.g. this {{ field.su%s }} % (unit.unit__id)

Comment: And if I just write {{ field }} I get this as output: <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x022B43F0>

Comment: I think the answer for me must be using formsets, maybe.

Comment: KillianDS: How would you do it then? I am very new to Django, so I'm not as well versed in template logic as you are.

Comment: @Brian: try `{{ field.render }}`. If not, I'll search some more.

Comment: @gruszczy: I encountered exactly the same problem.

Comment: I can access field.label. But when trying {{ field }}, it failed.

Comment: To have the code above working, change `self.subunit_list.append(field)` for `self.subunit_list.append(self['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])])`

Comment: @Brian, rom's answer fixes your issue. Add self['field_name'] to your list as opposed to the field object created by the IntegerField() constructor.

Answer (score 1):

To correct gruszczy's answer, this code worked for me:

In `__init__` of your form:

```
self.subunit_list = []
for subunit in self.selected_subunits:
        field = forms.IntegerField()
        self.fields['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])] = field
        self.subunit_list.append(self['su%d' % (subunit['unit__id'])])
```

In your template:

```
{% for field in form.subunit_list %}
  <!-- show form field (inputbox) -->
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```