# Next field django forms

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

If I am looping over a Form in a Django template how can I call the next Field? I would like to do something like this

```
{%for field in form%}
    {%if field.label|slice:':1' == "N"%}
        {{field+1}}
    {%endif%}
    {{field.label_tag}}
    {{field}}
    <ul class="errorlist" id="{{field.name}}_error"></ul>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @karthikr   I want obtain the next field of the form

Comment: Check this if this is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670711/django-form-fields-not-iterating-through-instance-fields