# Form fields in django templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form like the one below

```
class Form(forms.Form):
   chr1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
   email = forms.EmailField()
   chr2 = forms.CharField()
```

And my view code is like this

```
def template(request):
    form = Form({})
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

My template is like this

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I expect this to output a set of Input fields. But the above snippet is giving an output as given below

```
: chr1
: email
: chr2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [django: form.fields not iterating through instance fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670711/django-form-fields-not-iterating-through-instance-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) you should be iterating on the form object itself not the fields. So instead of form.fields, just use form.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I just found this duplicate question as well: [django: form.fields not iterating through instance fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670711/django-form-fields-not-iterating-through-instance-fields)

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is there a way I can **use just the fields and without form**, including template and view ? When I tried to pass a field from view and use it directly in the template I got `<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x02A8B030>`

Comment: My requirement is to dynamically add form fields and not a fixed set of fields.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean completely...but have you looked at FormSets?