# Iterate over Django custom Form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a dynamic form, with a varying number of CharFields. I want to be able to display them at will in semi-arbitrary places in my form. My approach was to create an iterable function that fielded the right self.fields[INDEX]. However, when I do this, I literally see this:

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x80bae6be0>
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x80bae6f98>
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x80bae6da0>
```

How do I make a CharField() render as expected?

My code is below:

```
class ImplementationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Specifies the implementation of a given control.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Implementation
        fields = ['implemented', 'scope', 'separate']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        control = kwargs.pop('control')

        super(ImplementationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['separate'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'separate'})
        self.fields['scope'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'scope'})

        for substatement in control.substatement.all():
            self.fields['statement_%s'%substatement.pk] = forms.CharField()

    def subfield(self):
        print("Comes herE")
        for index in self.fields:
            if index[:10] == 'statement_':
                yield self.fields[index]
```

The template basically does this:

```
{% for x in myform.subfield %} {{ x }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would recommend using [`FormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/). They provide the functionality you request out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the form's BoundFields. e.g. {{ form.email }}
You are iterating over the Field instances (not the form's BoundField instances that wraps the Field Instances) e.g. {{ form.field.email }}.
This is why you are getting the

> `<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x80bae6da0>`

result from your template. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/671305/3035260

Also see django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField

Try this dirty way (**See my edit below for a much better solution**):

```
{# Iterate over your list of field instances #}
{% for x in myform.subfield %}
  {# Find the matching BoundField instance #} 
  {% for field in myform %}
    {% if field.field == x %}
      {# Matching BoudField instance found, display it. #}
      {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:**
Just came across a better (less dirty) approach:
A Field has a

> get_bound_field(self, form, field_name)

method according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field.get_bound_field

So, in your subfield method in the last line (The 'yield' line), try this:

```
yield self.fields[index].get_bound_field(self, index)
```

Then, your template will remain the same:

```
{% for x in myform.subfield %} {{ x }} {% endfor %}
```

and everything should work as you intended.